# any way to fix mysql database tables missing mdy and mdi files

Tags: mysql, .net

We have mysql databases on two separate servers: one in dev and one in production.

Today at around the same time we ran into errors when querying: Fatal error encountered during command execution.

The db admin looked at the files, and says that there are no MDY or MDI files for the tables in the databases, and thinks that because of that, the database doesnt have indices and is having trouble. The app running against the databases has been working fine for about a month. We look our  nightly backups and the files never existed ( or maybe were not marked for backup?)

These databases used to be on mySQL 4.1.14-nt, and were moved over a server with mySQL 5.2 by using 
the mysqldump --add-drop=table command

Does this problem sound familiar to anyone? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that when we migrated the databases, mysqldump generated SQL that set the INNO data engine when creating tables in the schema.

INNO evidently doesnt use these MDY and MDI files.